# mysql trouble with information_schema.tables

Tags: mysql, sql

-edit2- 3hrs later and still have the same problem. I am using the noinstall archive package.
-edit- maybe someone can tell me a better way to check if a table exist?

I have a function in my lib to check if a table exist which i asked how to do in the past.

I deleted my database and created it again. My code didnt create the tables properly. After debugging i decided to write the below.

```
mysql> SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE tabl
e_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name='ApprovePost';
+--------------+-------------+
| table_schema | table_name  |
+--------------+-------------+
| mydb         | ApprovePost |
+--------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Weird... mydb was dropped and created again (i wrote `drop database mydb;` and `create database mydb;`. It should be gone?). Lets find out what exists

```
mysql> SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE tabl
e_schema = 'mydb';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Not only do i not know why the first statement shows tables which is wrecking my code, i dont know why this is not showing any tables (in that database).

note: The databases should all be innodb. Also this is a fresh windows install and i may have configured something wrong.

---

Bonus weirdness.

```
mysql> drop database mydb;
ERROR 1008 (HY000): Can't drop database 'mydb'; database doesn't exist
mysql> SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE tabl
e_schema = 'mydb';
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE tabl
e_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name='ApprovePost';
+--------------+-------------+
| table_schema | table_name  |
+--------------+-------------+
| mydb         | ApprovePost |
+--------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use the `FLUSH TABLES` command for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to reflect existing tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-cache.html

Comment: Now why isnt this an answer! ;) :D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the `FLUSH TABLES` command for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to reflect existing tables.

Reference:

- [TABLE CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...
Are results stable? May be some pending transaction..
What is shown by

```
show tables like '%'
```

Also it may be an issue with physical files.
Is folder for mydb exists?

Comment: mysql> show tables like '%';
Empty set (0.00 sec) -- i am checking the file now. It is created but i am going to delete and try a fresh folder.

Comment: still an issue. even in the older version. I wonder why i didnt notice it before. I wonder why it is doing this.

Comment: What is result for 'show database'? Does folder mydb exist im mysql data folder?