# How do I detect if a table exist? MySql

Tags: mysql, constraints

I was suggested to do this

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name='ApprovePost';
```

However it is not reliable and [cause me errors on several versions of mysql on windows and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169525/mysql-wtf-with-information-schema-tables).

Maybe there is another way. Does anyone know?

This issue is I can do create table if not exists but I do a second pass to add the FK constraint. In my SQL dump I see > 130 contains on a single table. The table only has 6 columns, only two of these need constrains. The constrains keep building and building every time I restart the Apache server or whenever mono feels the need to call my global init method in my webapp.

Comment: Is 'show tables' sql not good for you?

Comment: @Yehonatan: SHOW TABLES is a synonym for INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES on MySQL - see bottom of the page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html

Comment: Interesting, Yehonatan does not show it and i CAN write a WHERE on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the `FLUSH TABLES` command for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to reflect existing tables.

Reference:

- [TABLE CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-cache.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your only actual problem now is recreating the foreign key constantly (aside from a possibly broken MySQL install considering your other troubles), why not:

1) give it a constraint symbol (should be unique in database) and let the adding fail silently / catch 'em?

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT only_one_please FOREIGN KEY (columnname) ...
```

2) or better yet, add the foreign key clause in your `create table` in the first place?

As for the original question: I know no reason why this should happen, and I cannot recreate it. Selecting from information_schema is afaik quite the preferred way of checking this, and hasn't failed me yet. Aside from a brute force check like `SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT 0;` and checking for errors, you first might want to check for any other caching mechanisms besides MySQL's query cache, and if they're not there / not the problem, perhaps try a `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables`.

Comment: That looks different. I tested it, it seems to work. The problem is these FKs are generated (its our ORM). How do you propose on naming only_one_please? The amount of FKs in the table are known but info on other tables are not (but other tables doesnt matter?)

Comment: would something like this be ok? i assume i can reuse the same name (such as fk_0) on other tables? `ALTER TABLE post ADD CONSTRAINT fk_{0} FOREIGN KEY ...`, i

Comment: You can NOT use the same symbol for a constraint on other tables (unique per _database_), so naming on could be based on tablename+fieldname, or tablename+fk number (tablename_fk_0, tablename_fk_1 etc.).