# Bad to Grant reload permission in mysql?

Tags: mysql, permissions

Because of a problem i had with mysql [i need to use flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240164/how-do-i-detect-if-a-table-exist-mysql/3240548#3240548). I discovered the user cannot use flush without the reload permission. and to give it to him my syntax was

```
grant reload on *.* to 'webapp_wt'@'localhost';
```

I couldnt do specific_db.*. And granting this kind of permission doesnt feel right. Is there anything wrong with this? Is it possible for this mysql user to cause problems? (outside of the db i gave it permissions to).

-edit- exactly one view and one answer (and its good!) in 45mins. I am amused.

Is there a way to grant flush tables but nothing else?

Answer (score 3):

As it is a server administration thing, you indeed cannot grant it to specific databases/tables (much of which you can do with RELOAD would not make sense for a specific databse or table).

And yes, a user can seriously hinder performance with repeatedly FLUSH'ing tables or FLUSH QUERY CACHE, and can possibly break (lagging) replication with FLUSH MASTER.

Comment: Is there a way to allow flush tables but nothing else?

Comment: so the worse that can happen is hinder performance. Not actually break replication, binary logs, etc?

Comment: Even with solely FLUSH TABLES (which I don't think is possible), a `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` effectively blocks all alterations on the database, still not something you'd want.

Comment: Hm, this question and answer may be a bit dated. However, as far as I know it still applies. Whoever voted it down 3,5 years after answering, is very welcome to enlighten me...

Answer (score -2):

It's bad to grant any user access to an admin feature, especially if they dont understand/care about the impact of it behind the scenes (in this case the impact is potentially significant).

personally I would wrap it up in application logic. So instead of the user flushing the tables, he simply sets a flag in your database saying 'hey, i wanna flush'

You can then have script/cronjob which inspects the flag periodically, and add logic to decide when the flush should take place. This also means you get to keep all your admin priviledges to yourself == less headaches