# How do you get the max_length for a mysql field

Tags: sql, mysql

MySQL is returning the current field value length in property max_length.

I there a way to get the correct values ?

ie Field part_code is a varchar(32) that returns 3 if it contains the value of "ABC" instead of the expected result of 32

### EDIT

original mysql

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function build_fields(){
    $idx = 0;
    $num = @mysql_num_fields($this->qry);
    while($idx < $num){
        $field = mysql_fetch_field($this->qry, $idx);
        $this->fields[$field->name] = $field;
        $idx++;
    }
} // function build_fields()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

new mysqli

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
function build_fields(){

```
foreach(mysqli_fetch_fields($this->qry) as $name => $value){
    $this->fields[$name] = (array) $value;
}
```

} // function build_fields()
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Used 
DESCRIBE table_name 
and parsed the varchar(32) and int(4,2)

Comment: Can you show how you are returning this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to **Mark Baker**'s method , you can also get column information in several other ways:

```
SHOW  COLUMNS FROM table_name where field='field_name';
// OR
DESCRIBE table_name field_name;
```

Then you need to parse 'Type' column (it's returned as `varchar(32)`) to get the max length.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
       COLUMN_TYPE 
  FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MySchemaName'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName'
   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'MyColumnName'
```

Comment: +1: Might want to use [FLUSH TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html) prior - INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables can be cached: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240164/how-do-i-detect-if-a-table-exist-mysql