# fast test whether mysql was modified

Tags: mysql

Which is the best way of knowing whether a mysql table was modified (by an insert, update or delete)?

I'm looking for a mysql query which can tell me this. Is this possible?  My first attempt, was to make another table with the logs, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: MySQL's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables have been known to cache data - see this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240164/how-do-i-detect-if-a-table-exist-mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name'
       AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
```

and then by checking the `UPDATE_TIME`, you can tell when was the last time this table was modified.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on a recent version of MySQL you can examine the information schema

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'
```

to find the last time the table was updated.

See [How can I tell when a MySQL table was last updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307438/how-can-i-tell-when-a-mysql-table-was-last-updated/307488#307488) for additional comments.