# Checking if table exists on MySQL RDMS

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have here java code accessing mySQL database. It checks if table exists. The table is removed and does not exist, though code below is saying that the table exists.

```
private Boolean tableExists(String globalId) {
  // schema Test
  DBResult result =  db.selectQuery("SELECT table_name 
                                       FROM information_schema.tables 
                                      WHERE table_schema = '"+schema+"' 
                                        AND table_name = " + "\'" + "category_"+globalId.split("-")[1]+ "\'"+";");
  if(result.getRowCount() > 0) {
    logger.info(" Table exist "+globalId);
    return true; 
  } else {
    logger.info("table does not exist "+ globalId);
    return false;
  }
}
```

The method returns true that table exists. Later on, the program catches that the table does not exists and crashes. What is the problem, please? The program runs on Tomcat 6.

Comment: I don't quite understand, but have seen [sync issues when using INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169525/mysql-wtf-with-information-schema-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the `MySQL`. (Kill the process if necessary). That should work.

There are sync issues in `MySQL`.

Comment: Does that means that this way of programming is not acceptable if the data-base does not see what is happening in the real time?

Comment: well, I am not sure about that. Someone with more experience should be able to answer this one. Btw, did my solution work?

Comment: Your solution works, but that is not suitable for my program. This error is not acceptable for my program.

Comment: @ucas: If you find any other solution, please post it. I know, my solution is a pretty crude and non-elegant.